# sudden ubuntu 16.04 shutdown while downloading

Tags: scripts, disk-utility, powerpc

I am asking what happens if my laptops power dies while I am downloading a website on the Linux terminal? id like to know.Thanks.

Comment: If the hardware dies because of power, the OS (Ubuntu) can do nothing about it ..  Firmware can also shutdown your hardware automatically, eg. settings in the laptop that cause power-down if the device gets too hot (certain cpus do this automatically anyway) and Ubuntu, windoze or whatever you were running is just gone. My point is your hardware plays a huge part, then your settings (have you set power to sleep/hibernate because of inactivity (if downloading you're probably doing nothing thus triggering inactivity) etc)

Comment: @guiverc Could you post this as an answer please?

Comment: @George More details about what you are trying to do might get you some better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop power dies while downloading something, it won't be fully downloaded.  Depending on what software you are using to download it, when you next boot up you'll either see a partially downloaded but incomplete file, or the file won't be there (because it was downloaded to a temporary location while it was in progress).

Answer (score 0):

A PC/laptop/box can die for a number of reasons, a number of which an OS (Ubuntu or other) can do nothing about, for example

- cpu gets too hot; cpu shuts down instantly to protect itself  (many cpus slow themselves down prior to power-down threshold)
- motherboard/bios detects overheat, shuts itself down

No OS cannot protect itself from these, and you may see fsck (file system check) messages next boot detecting & fixing issues because of this next boot.

Further your settings can influence the outcome, eg. if you're downloading a large website (eg. i read your question as during a `wget -r`) it will take awhile & you'll likely step away and the system may detect itself as inactive & (depending on how it was done) suspend so it didn't complete when power ran out..

The effect of this power-out will depend on software used (refer @thomasrutter's answer) and where exactly it was in the process (had it just closed the file, written part, where buffers just flushed or buffering disabled? - some of this repeats @thomasrutter's answer too). Your settings can influence some of this (esp. buffering choices for speed or security/safety) but it can be just luck..